# Mysql connection from python docker image

Tags: python, mysql, docker

I have an application running inside of a docker container created starting from the official dockerhub python image (python:3.6.9-slim-stretch) https://hub.docker.com/_/python.

When I am trying to connect to an external database:

```
# mysql --host=myhost --user=mysuser--password=mypassword
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'muiser'@'EXTERNALH_HOST_NAME' (using password: YES)
```

If I try to use another docker image (i.e.: ubuntu:20.04), the same command executed from the same host node works fine:

```
# mysql --host=myhost --user=mysuser--password=mypassword
mysql>
```

I also tried to run the same command from the host, and it work fine.

Any idea of what can be the reason of such strange behavior?

Comment: probably when you are running it inside of the docker container you are connecting to a different database, and this is why you are receiving access denied.

to be sure try to ping and see which is the IP address that myhost is solving in each place

Comment: Unfortunately, pinging the database server points to the same IP address in both cases.